# Netbeans Collaborative Development

Tags: collaboration, netbeans-7

I'm trying to find a "simple" way of developing collaboratively with a team of 3 people.
We need a way to edit the same file simultaneously without any file loss

Perhaps if there isn't a plugin or software which can achieve this you could suggest a process we could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the build in [support](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mercurial.html) for [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) .